# how to add a result to a textbox from the database

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I want to calculate the sales commission for a sales person and place the result in a TextBox.

I have three tables:

1. Customer table
2. Sales Person table
3. Sales Person Commission

The Customer table is where the total amount payed is stored and also contains a foreign key of the sales person number which is the primary of the Sales Person table.

The Sales Person table contains the sales person details. The sales person commission table contains the Record Number,Sales Person number,number of sales made, commission percentage received, total commission and the month. The total commission is automatically calculated.

I have a query which calculates the sum of the total amount payed by the customer for a particular sales person eg:

```
Select SUM(Total_Amount) from Customer_Table where SP_No='" +textBox1.text + "'
```

How do I put this result into a text box so that the I don't have to enter the Number of Sales made in my sales commission form?

Comment: More info is needed. What database are you using, Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft Access?

Comment: Q: What language are you programming in?  You can do this with everything from a .Net Winform app to a PHP web application to an Excel spreadsheet.  How exactly are you planning on implementing this "text box"?

Comment: sry i am programming in C# and my database is sql server 2008

Comment: @paulsm4 it's tagged as C# post

Answer (score 1):

```
int GetSum(string no)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "select ... where sp_no = @no"; // note the param @no

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", no);

        connection.Open();
        return command.ExecuteScalar() as int? ?? 0; // 0 is default value
    }
}

txtSum.Text = GetSum(txtNo.Text).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas - the C# tag was added afterwards.

@Mirfath - as I said above, there are a zillion ways to do it.  If you're using C#, then I presume you're probably using WPF or WinForms for your "text box".

For WinForms, I would just use a ListBox or DataGridView and use your SQL as a DataSource:

http://blog.gfader.com/2008/09/winforms-listbox-vs-listview.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171884.aspx